# How to do Monte Carlo simulations in R

Tags: r, montecarlo

I have following information:

```
A = B/C
B has mean of 50 with SD of 10
C has mean of 3 with SD of 0.5
```

The distribution for all variables are presumed to be normal.

How can I run Monte Carlo simulation for such a situation? Thanks for your help.

Comment: See `?rnorm` and `?replicate`

Comment: I can get normal distribution and repetition with these. But how to perform the simulations? Would you recommend some package or some function for the same?

Comment: Do you want B and C to be correlated or related in some way, or are they independent?

Comment: A, B and C are related by the given formula though we can regard B and C to be independent.

Comment: The ratio of two normal random variables follows the Cauchy distribution and it can be generated by `rcauchy()`. It would have been a lot easier to answer if the specific goal were mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a rough Monte Carlo, you can run `n` experiment:

```
set.seed(1)
n = 1000
A = rnorm(n, 50, 10)/rnorm(n, 3, 0.5)
mean(A)
#[1] 17.09732
```